# SharePoint Discussion Board View to show one discussion thread

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-discussion-board

I need to show a particular thread that resides in a discussion board. I am currently trying to use SPViews.

The following is my code

```
        SPView threadedView = discussionBoard.Views["Threaded"];
    threadedView.Title = "Comments WebPart";

    //threadedView.Query = query.ToString();
    threadedView.RenderAsHtml();
```

however this view is giving me all the discussion threads in the discussion board not a single thread which is needed. tried also to set a query for the view but was useless. can anyone help pls.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for getting the Threaded View to work

http://snahta.blogspot.com/2011/06/displaying-paged-discussion-board.html

and

http://snahta.blogspot.com/2011/05/discussion-board-multiple-item-threaded.html